# IIS 8.5 - Server 2012 - Getting Default page

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-server-2012

I'm trying to narrow down a problem.

I have a few site hosted in IIS 8.5 on Server 2012. Each of the sites has a separate IP address associated with it. Just got it set up with the proper permissions and I have the default site running as well.

When I try to hit a service to a particular IP address I get the default IIS sites landing page when I should be seeing my service. I am only seeing this after waiting a while.

Is there a reason that I am getting the default site sometimes? How can I avoid this?

Comment: Do you have the default pages for that particular IP address set up to point at the page you are expecting?

Comment: Each of the sites have multiple web services. If I am pointing directly to the services its not a problem. Only when going directly to the IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have an issue with host headers.  The default web server will answer any request on any IP or host header.

Your bindings on the other servers likely have host header values.  If you navigate to the site via the IP address then those headers to not match and the default server will answer the request because it is setup for any IP and any host header. You can check the values by going to Administrative Tools | IIS Manager then click Sites, click your web server and then click Binding in the right pane.

If it is a public IP then use the fully qualified domain name (FQDN) to access the site instead of the IP (www.example.com).

If you need to access it on the internal network then you may have a DNS issue.  This will be the case if you need to access the private network IP instead of the public network IP.  In this case, I would suggest you edit your hosts file on the machine you are using to access the web server (windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts) and add an entry so that you can use the fully qualified domain name (FQDN) in the browsers address bar.

You can also remove your host headers in the Bindings for the web server, but that is likely not the correct solution.